# Integral of a function with respect to the measure $\nu(A)=\int_{A}fd\mu$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Question:

Given measure space $(X,\mathcal(A),\mu)$ and non-negative measurable function $f:X\to[0,\infty]$, consider the measure $\nu(A) = \int_{A}fd\mu$ defined for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$.  Prove that for any $\mu$-measurable function $g$, $$ \int_{X}gd\nu = \int_{X}fgd\mu $$

Attempted Solution:

I am thinking we can use (1) the fact that any measurable function $g$ is a pointwise limit of simple functions, and (2) monotone convergence theorem, to extend the result for simple functions

So let $\varphi$ be a simple function with canonical form $\sum_{k}a_k \chi_{a_k}$.  Then $$ \int_{X}\varphi d\nu = \sum_{k}a_{k}\nu(A_{k}) = \sum_{k}a_{k}\int_{A_{k}}fd\mu = \sum_{k}\int_{A_{k}}a_{k}fd\mu  $$

And hereI am stuck....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ be a non-negative simple measurable function of the cannonical form $\sum_{k}a_k \chi_{A_k}$ where $a_k\in [0,\infty)$ and $A_k$ are measurable sets. Then we have $$ \int_{X}\varphi\ \mathrm d\nu = \sum_{k}a_{k}\nu(A_{k}) = \sum_{k}a_{k}\int_Xf\chi_{A_k}\ \mathrm d\mu = \int_X\sum_ka_{k}\chi_{A_k}f\ \mathrm d\mu=\int_X\varphi f\ \mathrm d\mu$$

Now whenever $g$ is a non-negative measurable function we have a sequence $\{\varphi_n\}$ simple functions such that $0≤\varphi_1≤\varphi_2≤\cdots≤g$ and $\varphi_n \rightarrow g$ pointwise. Then we can apply Monotone Convergence Theorem,
$$\int_X g\ \mathrm d\nu=\lim\int_X\varphi_n \ \mathrm d\nu=\lim\int_X\varphi_nf\ \mathrm d\mu=\int_X\lim(\varphi_nf)\ \mathrm d\mu=\int_Xfg\ \mathrm d\mu$$ (Since $\{f\varphi_n\}$ is an increasing sequence of non-negative measurable functions converging point-wise to $fg$)

Now whenever $g$ is arbitrary measurable function write $g$ as $g=g^+-g^-$ where both $g^+=\max(g,0),\ g^-=\max(-g,0)$ both are non-negative measurable. Then we have $$\int_X fg^+\ \mathrm d\mu=\int_X g^+\ \mathrm d\nu$$ and $$\int_X fg^-\ \mathrm d\mu=\int_X g^-\ \mathrm d\nu$$ Hence $g$ is $\nu$ integrable if $g$ is $\mu$ integrable, and in this case we can write $$\int_Xg\ \mathrm d\nu=\int_X g^+\ \mathrm d\nu-\int_Xg^-\ \mathrm d\nu=\int_Xfg^+\ \mathrm d\mu-\int_Xfg^-\ \mathrm d\mu=\int_Xfg\ \mathrm d\mu$$

Comment: I assume in the last part i.e part which starts with "when $g$ is arbitrary measurable function...." that $f$ is $\mu$ integrable.

Answer (score 4):

$$\cdots=\int\left(\sum_k a_k\chi_{A_k}\right)fd\mu=\int\phi fd\mu$$

Comment: wow yes... Thanks!  I am also not confident that I am using simple functions/monotone convergence correctly.  It feels so much like cheating that I feel like I'm missing something... Do you see anything wrong with the use of those?

Comment: Nothing wrong. It is correct to go first for indicator functions, then for nonnegative simple functions, then for nonnegative measurable functions and finally for integrable functions. By the nonnegative measurable functions you use the definition $\int fd\mu=\sup\{\int gd\mu\mid g\leq f\text{ and }g\text{ simple}\}$